# Django filter based on specific item from reverse relation

Tags: python, django

I have two models that could look something like this:

```
Course(models.Model):
  pass

WeeklyPrice(models.Model):
  num_weeks = models.IntegerField()
  price = models.DecimalField()
  course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
  is_erased = models.BooleanField()
```

The thing is i have a search form, which needs to be able to filter by minimum number of weeks.

On Course creation, a bunch of `WeeklyPrices` are also created, which can then be deleted (logically by setting is_erased to True), so a good example would be that Course has 13 instances of WeeklyPrice, starting at week 4, because weeks 1, 2 and 3 have been deleted.

So how can i retrieve a queryset of `Courses` with an instance of `WeeklyPrice` whose `num_weeks` is less or equal to the `duration` variable retrieved from the search form?

Comment: could i at least get a comment about why this is getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i ended up finding out it's a lot simpler than it sounds...

The filter needed is:

```
courses.filter(weekly_prices__is_erased=False, weekly_prices__num_weeks=duration)
```